# QT 5 android, Change background_running value to True

Tags: android, qt, qt5

Does anyone know how to change the meta-data values from the QT project for an android deploy.  I need to set the background_running to true.  I can do that manually, and everything works, but the next times I change the code, this value is reset back to false.

Anyone know how to edit these values from the QT project so the value persists between code changes?

```
 <!-- Background running -->
 <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                application still try to draw after
                "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                signal is sent! -->
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

From QT creator, go into projects -> android build options -> Details on build android APK

Click create templates, ensure gradle is selected, now you can edit the template AndroidManifest.xml and set the option to true.  All future builds will use this AndroidManifest.xml.  You can also now easily extend the QtActivity by editing the manifest.

Comment: Do you get unexpected crashes as stated in comment?

Comment: No the "unexpected crashes" will happen if you're attempting to do UI things while you don't have the window view.  If you correctly monitor applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state), you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, nothing should happen in QML while it's in background?

Comment: That's a question for the QT dev's.  I setup my programs to run all the app logic in C++ and QML is just for displaying user info.  Not sure if you can run QML logic in the background, my guess is yes?  I do know that running GUI updates while in background can/does crash your app.