# What does "android.app.background_running" in AndroidManifest.xml mean?

Tags: android, qt, android-manifest

Basically, the question is in the title.

- What does this option do?
- What does it influence?
- How is it related to
  Activity lifecycle and/or Service lifecycle?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="org.example.test" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="0.1" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.StartActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                      application still try to draw after
                      "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                      signal is sent! -->
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
</manifest>
```

It is used in QT apps for Android, but I thought it has nothing to do with QT since it is in manifest. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please post a manifest that demonstrates where and how this value is being used.

Comment: I believe that is used in `QT`

Answer (score 2):

Since this option has really nothing to do with Android API as I thought before, I started digging into QT sources what that means.

Setting this option will export `QT_BLOCK_EVENT_LOOPS_WHEN_SUSPENDED` environment variable, which will be checked by QT native code and will stop event dispatcher (no `QCoreApplication::processEvents` will be called since then) for QT part of the app when the main Activity was stopped or paused by `onStop(`) and `onPause()` methods. So that is what means "freezing" the event loop.

I don't know of all cautions one should be aware of, but I will update my answer as soon as I find it out.

Answer (score 1):

After long search this is what I found

> What does this option do?

Setting **android.app.background_running** to `true` means don’t freeze the Qt main loop, but you must make sure you don’t draw anything when the application is backgrounded.

This SO answer says how can we change its default value [QT 5 android, Change background_running value to True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523403/qt-5-android-change-background-running-value-to-true)

Comment: Well, this is no surprise, but I've seen that myself, though it doesn't explain how this option influences app behavior and what other things I need to do by "making sure I don't draw anything" and what other things I might need to do if I want to handle app being in background/foreground etc.

Comment: @rightaway717: Sorry to say but I also started to look for it once I saw your post. :(